# assert not cls._meta.auto_field, ( AssertionError: Model shop.Product can't have more than one auto-generated field

Tags: django, django-models

I got following error:

```
assert not cls._meta.auto_field, ( AssertionError: Model shop.Product can't have more than one auto-generated field )
```

Here is my `Product` class code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="shop/images", default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the whole model. Are you extending models.Model?

Comment: Hi, Shaikh. To get help with your issue can I recommend you to several tips: Avoid upper case text (this mean you are yelling), Put a short title which tell what this is about, Provide info and context question, Write a question phrase with a question mark to guide what you want as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, and i resolve doing that:

1 - Move to trash old migrate

2 - run `python manage.py makemigrations`

3 - run `python manage.py migrate`

if your problem persist, try to delete table into a data base ( if you do that, you lost your admin user, you can create another with `python manage.py createsuperuser`